# verify and publish when using oraclize?

Tags: etherscan, oracles, abi, bytecode, verify

I'm using oraclize in my contract.

```
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";
```

When I go to verify and publish on etherscan I get this error

```
myc:4:1: ParserError: Source "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol"
^--------------------------------------------------------^
```

Any idea how too fix this?

Comment: The contract works fine and it's on solidity 5.4

Answer (score 1):

In several Oraclize Truffle Examples, such as [Diesel-Price](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/truffle-examples/diesel-price/contracts/DieselPrice.sol), the Oraclize API code is copied and pasted in a smart contract and then imported as follow:

```
import "./oraclizeAPI.sol";
```

Please, note that you have to use `./` just when `yourContract.sol` and the `oraclizeApi.sol` are in the same path.

The `oraclizeAPI.sol` is the **whole** API provided by Oraclize: [oraclizeAPI.sol](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/truffle-examples/diesel-price/contracts/oraclizeAPI.sol)

Comment: I copied the code from oraclizeAPI.sol and pasted it in my solidity code. above my contract declaration but below pragma solidity ^0.5.4; commented out //pragma solidity >= 0.5.0; // Incompatible compiler version - please select a compiler within the stated pragma range, or use a different version of the oraclizeAPI!
Everything worked fine! Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1):

To add to Riccardo's answer:

Importing from GitHub is a Remix-specific function, and is not standard Solidity code. Instead, you can download the `oraclizeAPI.sol` from the [source repository](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api), and add it to your project.

Then you can import it, like Riccardo said in the other answer.

```
import "./oraclizeAPI.sol";
```

Comment: You're missing "; from the end of your import string. Otherwise, the answer is good.